# Cannot set option value in select programmatically using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

**The select**:

```
select(ng-model="elId", ng-change="load(elId)", ng-options="e._id as e.name for e in options")
    option(value="") - select a mashup -
```

**Controller**:

The following works, the select gets populated. I am using broadcasts because it comes from a socket.. don't mind that.

```
 //receive list
 $scope.$on('list:refresh', function(ev, data) {
     $scope.options = data
 })
```

The following only works if I did not manually select any option before. `data.id` is a valid entry in the list.

```
 //refresh list of mashups when a new one has been created
 $scope.$on('list:select', function (ev, data) {  
     $scope.elId = data.id
 })
```

If I manually select an option, and then the `list:select` fires, the `$scope.elId` is udated but the `<select>` does not highlight the option.

What is going on?

Comment: Your issue appears to be the fact that you're not utilizing the `ng-selected` directive. Check [out the docs here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSelected)

Comment: that cold be a problem, too.. but not in this case, see my answer :) thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

**The select**:

```
select(ng-model="data.elId", ng-change="load()", ng-options="e._id as e.name for e in options")
    option(value="") - select a mashup -
```

**Controller**:

```
 //receive list
 $scope.$on('list:refresh', function(ev, data) {
     $scope.options = data
 })

 $scope.load() {
    var elId = $scope.data.elId
    ....
 }

 //refresh list of mashups when a new one has been created
 $scope.$on('list:select', function (ev, data) {  
     $scope.data.elId = data.id
 })
```

I guess the problem was that I tried to change the selected value from a child controller.. now I am using a service Data that I load into the controllers `$scope.data = Data`.. meh?

Comment: I think what solved the issue is you changing the ng-model from a simple variable to the property of an object. This seems like a common problem with ng-model in angular. I have fought it a few times.

Comment: Oh, I see - gotta remember that! :) Just lost few hours for that problem :P

Comment: I know, me too. That has to be high on the list of Angular gotchas.